# How to check multiple borders on a grid

Tags: c++

I have a assignment in which I have a 20x40 grid of (x,y) locations. The user moves around in this grid using the arrow keys. The grid starts as all "." periods and the cursor leaves " " spaces in it's wake so the user knows where he has traveled already.

Every time the user inputs a character the program runs a function given by my instructor that checks if it is an arrow key ( ANSII characters 72, 75, 77, and 80), and if so, it moves the cursor.

```
//Take in user input to move around the grid
void Move(char Direction)
{
    switch (static_cast<int>(Direction))
    {
    case 72: //Up arrow
        Screen[xPos][yPos] = ' '; //Wipe out the users current cursor
        xPos--; //Move the users x position on the grid
        Screen[xPos][yPos] = '^'; //Move the users cursor
        break;
    case 80: //Down arrow
        Screen[xPos][yPos] = ' ';
        xPos++;
        Screen[xPos][yPos] = 'V';
        break;
    case 75: //Left arrow
        Screen[xPos][yPos] = ' ';
        yPos--;
        Screen[xPos][yPos] = '<';
        break;
    case 77: //Right arrow
        Screen[xPos][yPos] = ' ';
        yPos++;
        Screen[xPos][yPos] = '>';
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to create borders for the cursor. I can create a conditional statement that steps in between the user's input and the function, but I do not know how to check multiple borders at the same time.

My current solution is to create an upper border conditional for the up command inside the movement function, a lower border conditional for the down command, etc.
This breaks the rules of the assignment as I cannot modify the move function.

Is there a way to slip a border check in before the function, and if so can I check multiple borders at once?

Here is the portion of main in question.

```
system("cls"); //Clear the screen before printing anything
    cout << "Welcome to cookie pickup. You will move to the cookies by using the arrow keys." << endl; //Program intro
    Game->Print(); //Print the grid out
    cout << "What direction would you like to move in? \n(Move using the arrow keys or type q to quit.) "; //Instructions to the user                                                                                                      
    UserMove = _getche(); //Get one character from the user (Visual Studio 2010 "_getche()" is the new version of "getche()")
    Game->Move(UserMove); //Process the users input
```

Comment: You don't need to `static_cast`, just `switch` on the `char`. Also why not implement a function that throws an exception if you move out of bounds, then call something like `move(0, 1)` to move x,y (0,1) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the validity of the move writing a function

```
// your boundaries
const int TOP = 10;
const int BOT = 0;
const int LEFT = 0;
const int RIGHT = 10;

// the moves
const char MOVE_UP = 72;
const char MOVE_DOWN = 80;
const char MOVE_LEFT = 75;
const char MOVE_RIGHT = 77;

bool isValid(char move){
   return !(
     (yPos == TOP && move == MOVE_UP) ||
     (yPos == BOT && move == MOVE_DOWN) ||
     (xPos == RIGHT && move == MOVE_RIGHT) ||
     (xPos == LEFT && move == MOVE_LEFT)
   );
}
```

Then you can move only if the requested direction does not push you outside the borders:

```
if (isValid(dir)){
     Move(dir);
}
```